# Because the IN clause () SQL Server does not work this way

Tags: sql, sql-server

see if someone can get me this question:
This is my SQL query which loads into a temporary table for which to consult posterirormente there all goes well:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+' ,' , '') + sCodProducto 
FROM dbo.Productos WHERE sCodProducto IN (80063, 80061, 80067, 80062, 80065)

INSERT INTO #IDPROD2(CODIGO) 
SELECT @listStr
```

**if I make this a select shows me the following data:**

```
SELECT * FROM #IDPROD2
```

[image]

**Well, now if I consult so this brings me nothing:**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Productos P WHERE P.sCodProducto IN (SELECT CODIGO FROM #IDPROD2)
```

**now if it works this way:**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Productos P WHERE P.sCodProducto IN (80061 ,80062 ,80063 ,80065 ,80067)
```

Comment: Use a table value parameter and inner join to it.

Comment: Because a string scalar variable is a single value.  It is not interpreted as code or a list.  It's the difference between `IN (1, 2, 3)` and `IN ('1, 2, 3')`

Comment: Tank you @matBaile

Comment: how could convert this:
'80061,80062,80063,80065,80067,80075'
in this:
'80061','80062','80063','80065','80067','80075'

Answer (score 5):

A field in a query result is considered a single **VALUE**. The actual contents of that field are irrelevant. Doesn't matter if you have a numbers in CSV format, or one single number - that entire chunk of data is one single VALUE, as far as the DB is concerned.

Since it's a single value, your `codigo` field's contents are parsed/executed as:

```
... WHERE foo IN (@codigo)
... WHERE foo IN ('1,2,3,4,...');
... WHERE foo = '1,2,3,4,....';
```

The DB will **NOT** parse those values, and therefore will **NOT** treat string as multiple distinct values.

If you want the contents of a single field or variable to be treated as multiple distinct values, you have to use dynamic sql:

```
sql = "SELECT .... WHERE foo IN (" + @codigo + ")";
exec @sql;
```

Note that this is basically a form of SQL injection. You remove the "context" of being a single value from that variable field, and force the DB to treat it as multiple different values.

Some DBs get around this by providing extract functions, e.g. mysql's `find_in_set`, which is designed specifically for this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('80063', '80063, 80061, 80067, 80062, 80065');
```

There is no such function in TSQL, but can be simulated, even with a simple `like` query:

```
... WHERE foo='80063' OR foo LIKE '80063,%' OR foo LIKE '%,80063,%' OR foo LIKE '%,80063'
```

Comment: `','+@list+',' LIKE '%,'+field+',%'`

Comment: how could convert this:
'80061,80062,80063,80065,80067,80075'
in this:
'80061','80062','80063','80065','80067','80075'

Comment: they're integers. they don't need to be quoted. just strip off the leading/trailing quotes.